# how do you fix this while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

**EDIT: i have another problem but it won't let me post again**

the code is this:

```
print('''Which group of queens do you want to compete against?
1. Winners
2. Runner-ups
3. Lip sync assassins
4. Miss Congenialities
5. First Eliminated
6. Returning queens''')
choice = int(input())

while choice > 6:
  if choice == 1:
    contestants = ["BeBe Zahara Benet", "Tyra Sanchez", "Raja", "Sharon Needles", "Jinkx Monsoon", "Bianca Del Rio", "Violet Chachki", "Bob the Drag Queen", "Sasha Velour", "Aquaria", "Yvie Oddly", "Chad Michaels", "Alaska", "Trixie Mattel", "Trinity the Tuck", "Monét X Change"]
  elif choice == 2:
    contestants = ["Nina Flowers", "Raven", "Manila Luzon", "Chad Micheals", "Alaska", "Courtney Act", "Ginger Minj", "Kim Chi", "Peppermint", "Eureka", "Brooke Lynn Hytes", "Katya", "Kennedy Davenport", "Monique Heart"]
  elif choice == 3:
    contestants = ["Akashia", "Jujubee", "Alexis Mateo", "Latrice Royale", "Coco Montrese", "Trinity K. Bonet", "Kennedy Davenport", "Chi Chi DeVayne", "Peppermint", "Kameron Michaels", "Ra'Jah O'Hara", "Raven", "Alaska", "BenDeLaCreme", "Trinity the Tuck"]
  elif choice == 4:
    contestants = ["Nina Flowers", "Pandora Boxx", "Yara Sofia", "Latrice Royale", "Ivy Winters", "BenDeLaCreme", "Katya", "Cynthia Lee Fontaine", "Valentina", "Monét X Change", "Nina West"]
  elif choice == 5:
    contestants = ["Victoria Parker", "Shangela", "Venus D-Lite", "Alisa Summers", "Penny Tration", "Kelly Mantle", "Tempest DuJour", "Laila McQueen", "Jaymes Mansfield", "Vanessa Vanjie Mateo", "Soju", "Mimi Imfurst", "Coco Montrese", "Thorgy Thor", "Jasmine Masters"]
  elif choice == 6:
    contestants = ["Carmen Carrera", "Shangela", "Kenya Michaels", "Trixie Mattel", "Naysha Lopez", "Cynthia Lee Fontaine", "Eureka", "Vanessa Vanjie Mateo", "Alyssa Edwards", "Tatianna", "Morgan McMichaels", "Latrice Royale", "Manila Luzon"]
  else:
    while choice > 6 or choice < 1:
        print("Please choose one of the 6 groups")
        choice = int(input())
```

the section that doesn't work is this:

```
else:
    while choice > 6 or choice < 1:
        print("Please choose one of the 6 groups")
        choice = int(input())
```

the loop keeps going on and on no mater what i enter (unless i enter anything other than an integer where it'll show an error message). how do i stop this when i enter an integer between 1 and 6?

Comment: `contestants` is likely an empty sequence.

Comment: with double quotations on `likely`

Comment: try `print(contestants[int(x)])`

Comment: what if choice ==0 ?

Comment: Everything in `while choices > 6` will be skipped if you enter a valid value.

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: Why don't You accept an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may never get out from your `while` loop if `choice` < 6 so your program will never hit your `for` loop

to fix you can make a `dict` to hold all your options, read one time the  `input` and base on the input create `contestants`

```
options = {
    1: ["BeBe Zahara Benet", "Tyra Sanchez", "Raja", "Sharon Needles", "Jinkx Monsoon", "Bianca Del Rio", "Violet Chachki", "Bob the Drag Queen", "Sasha Velour", "Aquaria", "Yvie Oddly", "Chad Michaels", "Alaska", "Trixie Mattel", "Trinity the Tuck", "Monét X Change"],
    2: ["Nina Flowers", "Raven", "Manila Luzon", "Chad Micheals", "Alaska", "Courtney Act", "Ginger Minj", "Kim Chi", "Peppermint", "Eureka", "Brooke Lynn Hytes", "Katya", "Kennedy Davenport", "Monique Heart"],
    3: ["Akashia", "Jujubee", "Alexis Mateo", "Latrice Royale", "Coco Montrese", "Trinity K. Bonet", "Kennedy Davenport", "Chi Chi DeVayne", "Peppermint", "Kameron Michaels", "Ra'Jah O'Hara", "Raven", "Alaska", "BenDeLaCreme", "Trinity the Tuck"],
    4: ["Nina Flowers", "Pandora Boxx", "Yara Sofia", "Latrice Royale", "Ivy Winters", "BenDeLaCreme", "Katya", "Cynthia Lee Fontaine", "Valentina", "Monét X Change", "Nina West"],
    5: ["Victoria Parker", "Shangela", "Venus D-Lite", "Alisa Summers", "Penny Tration", "Kelly Mantle", "Tempest DuJour", "Laila McQueen", "Jaymes Mansfield", "Vanessa Vanjie Mateo", "Soju", "Mimi Imfurst", "Coco Montrese", "Thorgy Thor", "Jasmine Masters"],
    6: ["Carmen Carrera", "Shangela", "Kenya Michaels", "Trixie Mattel", "Naysha Lopez", "Cynthia Lee Fontaine", "Eureka", "Vanessa Vanjie Mateo", "Alyssa Edwards", "Tatianna", "Morgan McMichaels", "Latrice Royale", "Manila Luzon"]
}

print('''Which group of queens do you want to compete against?
1. Winners
2. Runner-ups
3. Lip sync assassins
4. Miss Congenialities
5. First Eliminated
6. Returning queens''')

choice = int(input())
while choice > 6 or choice < 1:
    print("Please choose one of the 6 groups")
    choice = int(input())

contestants = options[choice]
```

Comment: @RyanLaker check now my answer

Comment: @RyanLaker if this post was useful you can upvote or accept the answer, thx!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** As I see you added more code. You are checking if your choice is **greater than** 6, then compare to values less than 6. You never hit that `while` loop.

No need to loop through the indexes. Loop through the list directly.

```
for x in contestants:
    print(x)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: While the recommendation is valid, it does not explain the observed code behaviour.